# Since the general formula of redshift only depends on the metric of the source and the observer, how do we end up with Integrated Sachs-Wolfe effect?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, redshift

To my knowledge, the most general expression of the redshift in cosmology is the following:

$1+z=\frac{\left(g_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}u^{\nu}\right)_{S}}{\left(g_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}u^{\nu}\right)_{O}}$

where :

- $S$ is the source and $O$ the observer
- $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric
- $k^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}$ is the coordinate derivative regarding the affine parameter $\lambda$
- $u^{\nu}$ is the 4-velocity of the cosmic fluid

(let me know if I'm wrong). What's interesting to me is that the formula just depend on the source and observer. But if we think of a photon that travels from a source to the observer without encountering any void or supercluster versus a photon that travels encoutering voids and superclusters, the Integrated Sachs-Wolfe effect will not be the same. Where does ISW come from using the general redshift formula?

Comment: Cosmology doesn't care about the small stuff. It assumes homogeneity and isotropy. The Sachs-Wolfe effect seems to care about some of the small stuff at the time of the surface of last scattering. There is also the "integrated SW effect" and it seems to care about more of the small stuff. What you are talking about is, I believe, neither. That is full scale weak lensing.

Comment: If you want to take the inhomogeneities into account you don't divide the source by the observer but integrate from one to the other, for which you'd need some other metric than the FLRW since that is isotropic and homogenous so the effect you're looking for doesn't occur there.